# SNMP monitoring of iostat on a Solaris 10 server?

Tags: solaris, snmp, iostat

I'm looking at the System Management Agent resources which gives guidance to the Solaris SNMP tools however after extensive googling I can't find any OID reference list or details on what can be monitored; I'm looking for iostat in particular.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Once I figure out how/whether I can configure the snmp agent to track iostat r/w bandwidth and unitilisation the plan will be to monitor with OpenNMS. So any OpenNMS specific guides would be super useful.

Dwight

Answer (score -1):

Have you had a look here: http://www.mibdepot.com/cgi-bin/vendor_index.cgi?r=sun

You could also try loading the mibs into a mib browser, see what there is available.

hth.